# Wiremock Snapshotting with simulated delay

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-record

Wiremock version: 2.27.0

Using Wiremock to run load testing, with the following workflow.

a. Proxy enabled and a single run of Load testing is executed (warm-up phase).

b. Generate SnapShot

c. Then modify the mapping (getting/setting via REST API), and decorate it with `delayDistribution`

d. Run Subsequent Load test runs (the actual runs, that contribute to final stats)

Is there a better way to do this? For instance, is there a way to decorate existing mapping with DelayCharacteristics. I looked into the extensions, but could not find a more elegant method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no read-made solution for you to download and implement. However, it is possible for you to develop yourself.

In the WireMock documentation on Record and Playback the section on [Transforming generated stubs](http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/#transforming-generated-stubs) by creating an extension based on `StubMappingTransformer`.

There is also some documentation to be found here in the [example](https://github.com/ePages-de/epages-devportal/blob/a113e9f21ab6bcc10e7b4bb2ec2f90c58c605cae/_posts/2018/2018-03-06-how-to-mock-external-services-for-api-tests.md).